# Should I suggest an edit to rollback an edit?

Tags: discussion

I recently made [this suggested edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/36499) to an answer to fit with the edit that had been made to the question (being specific about Apple's **UK** Support site).

[image: My suggested edit]

An [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/100250/revisions) was then made to add the region to the link, however the incorrect region was added (US instead of UK).

[image: @bmike's edit]

As per the guidelines, I should avoid trivial, tiny one-letter edits, and suggested edits must be longer than 6 characters anyway.

Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case - false information trumps the general prohibition to make a trivial edit. Sadly, the system won't even let us fix that one typo so we have to change more or use two edits to effect a one character change.

I wouldn't roll back, but just edit it correct going forward.

Great catch.

*btw - that bmike fellow often is on an iPad and making silly typos when trying to improve a suggested edit*

Comment: What should I do about the "*Edits must be at least 6 characters*"?

Comment: The main reason why I suggested a rollback is because of the character requirement for suggested edits.

Comment: I too was hobbled by the character requirement, so I made sure to improve things with some more details that I know to be true (like chat windows are only drawn when people are scheduled to be chatting).